# Intersection of line segments induced by point sets from fixed geometry

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, computational-geometry, algorithm-design

I am reading up on algorithms and at the moment looking at the below problem from Jeff Erickson's book [Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1792644833).

[image: Problem 14 snippet from Recursion chapter out of Algorithms book by Jeff Erickson]

I solved (a) by seeing a relationship to the previous problem on computing the number of array inversions. However, I am struggling with problem (b) as I cannot see how to reduce the circle point arrangement to an arrangement of points and lines that would be an input to the problem posed in (a). Assuming I have something for (b), I also cannot see how one might resolve (c).

For part (b), clearly every point $p = (x, y)$ satisfies $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ but I do not see how I might be able to use this fact to do the reduction. The runtime I am shooting for of $O(n \log^2 n)$ also seems to tell me the reduction is going to cost something non-trivial to do.

Can anyone have some further hints/insights that might help with part (b) and potentially even part (c)?

Comment: I think looking at it algebraically is the wrong direction. Look at it geometrically (Jeff is a computational geometer, after all). Maybe this will help: suppose there is a line that intersects all segments in the circle. Can you solve it now? Of course, there does not have to be such a line (try to find a counterexample!), but you now have solved at least part of the problem. I suppose the chapter has taught you what to do next.

Comment: @Discretelizard I appreciate the response! I read your comment and thought I had something good, but it seems I do not totally see how to work the idea in. If such a line exists, I would also need to to be able to compute such a line. It also seems this algorithm needs to partition the segments into two equal sized sets and run the algo recursively on each partition, while also solving an instance similar to part (a) at each level of the recursion, if I want to end up with the $O(n \log^2 n)$ runtime. However, I'm not sure how to end up with a correct algo that does this, even with your hint.

Comment: Well, just like in the previous exercise, you do not need the full coordinates of you position. There's no need to compute the line itself. Also, there is no need to determine whether the particular line I mentioned exists. Take an arbitrary line that intersects the circle twice. Which segments intersect this line, and how do you count the intersections among the segments that are not intersected by this line?